# Access another database table in Grails while iterating

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have these models

Game.groovy

```
class Game {
    String gameTitle
    static hasMany = [screenshot: Screenshots list:GameList]
}
```

GameList.groovy

```
class GameList {
    static belongsTo = [game : Game , category : GameCategory]  
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

GameCategory.groovy

```
class GameCategory {
    String categoryName
    String icon
    String toString(){
        "${categoryName}"
    }
    static hasMany = [ list:GameList]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In my controller
GameController.groovy

```
def listGame(){
    def category = GameCategory.list()
    def currentCategory = params.categoryName
    def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(currentCategory)
    def game = GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{it.game}
    [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, game:game]     
}
```

In my view I iterated all games to display every game in a certain category.
Additionally, I want to display all the categories of every game. How do I access the category of each game on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your domain model, you can't access the game categories from a `Game` instance because there's no way to navigate the associations from `Game` to `GameCategory`. Keeping with the same domain model, here's a hack:

```
def listGame(){
    def category = GameCategory.list()
    def currentCategory = params.categoryName
    def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(currentCategory)
    def game = GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{it.game}
    def gameCategories = GameList.withCriteria {
        inList 'game', game

        projections {
            property 'game'
            property 'category'
        }
    }.groupBy { it[0] }
    .collectEntries { game, record -> [(game): record*.getAt(1)] }

    [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, game:game, gameCategories: gameCategories]     
}
```

`gameCategories` is a `Map<Game, List<GameCategory>>`, loosely speaking, which contains all of the `GameCategory`s for each `Game` in the `game` variable. You can pass it to your view and use it to look up the `GameCategory`s of the `Game`s: `def categories = gameCategories[gameInstance]`

But, you can simply all of this by using a different domain model, as follows:

## An alternative domain model

```
class Game {
    String gameTitle
    static hasMany = [screenshot: Screenshots, categories: GameCategory]
}

class GameCategory {
    String categoryName
    String icon
    String toString(){
        "${categoryName}"
    }
    static hasMany = [games: Game]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Now, a `Game` *has many* `GameCategory`s and a `GameCategory` *has many* `Game`s. With such a model, `listGame()` can be simplified:

```
def listGame(){
    def currentCategory = params.categoryName
    def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(currentCategory)
    def games = myCategory.games

    [currentCategory:currentCategory, games: games]     
}
```

Then, in your view you can render the games and categories like this:

```
<g:each var="game" in="${games}">
    <!-- Render game -->
    <g:each var="category" in="${game.categories}">
        <!-- Render the game's category -->
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Comment: The altered domain model is really the way to go.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong post Game model supposed to have
 static hasMany = [screenshot: Screenshots list:GameList]

doesn't it need to have associative entity when the relationship is many to many? which is GameList?

Comment: Nope, gorm creates the mapping/join table for you.

Comment: GameList is only getting in the way. You're better off without it. Gorm can handle the many to many directly between the category and game.

Comment: I have an error while running it
"Error loading plugin manager: No owner defined between domain classes [class gameplify.Game] and [class gameplify.GameCategory] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = gameplify.GameCategory (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)"

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. You just need to add `static belongsTo = GameCategory` to the `Game` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of **every** `Game` and all of associated `GameCategory`'s with that game:

```
def gamesAndCategories = Game.list().collect{ Game g ->
    def matchingCategories = GameList.findAllByGame(g)*.category

    return [game: g, categories: matchingCategories]
}
```

You can replace `Game.list()` with a collection of `Game`'s if you want associated `GameCategory`'s for a particular subset of `Game`'s.

You can then add `gamesAndCategories` to your existing returned map and use it in your view.